# Linux GPIOs handling

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, gpio, sysfs

I have some question about Linux kernel and GPIOs. I know that in Linux everything is file so when I do something like

```
echo 30 > /sys/class/gpio/export
```

and

```
echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio30/value
```

what really happens? I mean how does sysfs handle that? Does it call system calls implemented in gpiolib?

Comment: See this answer for a good use of sysfs and GPIOs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19257624/interrupt-handling-and-user-space-notification/19258745#19258745

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [gpiolib](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/gpio/gpiolib.c) registers the value attribute in this way:

```
 static const DEVICE_ATTR(value, 0644, gpio_value_show, gpio_value_store);
```

It creates a device attribute named `value`, with permission `644`; on read it calls `gpio_value_show`, on write it calls `gpio_value_store`

What sysfs does, is to redirect `read` and `write` to the correspondent function of a sysfs attribute.