# Linux kernel gpio code behind the scenes?

Tags: c, linux, kernel, gpio

I'm trying to understand what happens behind the scenes when you write to gpio "files".

From what I found ([Linux GPIOs handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19548449/linux-gpios-handling)), it is not really writing to a file but sysfs maps open/read/write to other functions.

But the newer version (http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/gpio/gpiolib.c ) doesn't  contain DEVICE_ATTR.
Instead:

```
2242 int gpiod_direction_input(struct gpio_desc *desc)
2243 {
2244         struct gpio_chip        *chip;
2245         int                     status = -EINVAL;
2246 
2247         VALIDATE_DESC(desc);
2248         chip = desc->gdev->chip;
2249 
2250         if (!chip->get || !chip->direction_input) {
2251                 gpiod_warn(desc,
2252                         "%s: missing get() or direction_input() operations\n",
2253                         __func__);
2254                 return -EIO;
2255         }
2256 
2257         status = chip->direction_input(chip, gpio_chip_hwgpio(desc));
2258         if (status == 0)
2259                 clear_bit(FLAG_IS_OUT, &desc->flags);
2260 
2261         trace_gpio_direction(desc_to_gpio(desc), 1, status);
2262 
2263         return status;
2264 }
2265 EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL(gpiod_direction_input);
```

I've been going through the code for 3 hours and i still can't unsterstand what is happening

- Would it be possible to get a detailed flow of this mechanism?
- Starting from writing to export and read/write a value from a gpio what code is executed?
- How does the code go from a value to "file" to a function with a struct gpio_desc *desc param?
- Where does the mapping of functions happen? (I can't find the export macro)

Comment: It's setting the direction of a pin to input. It also clears the flag in desc to track the state. The rest is error checking and logging.  Export means the call is exported if you comply with GPL.

Comment: The sysfs file-handling code is in http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/gpio/gpiolib-sysfs.c .

Comment: Thx that makes things a little clearer, but im still stuck on the general flow : going from writing a value to a file to executing a func with the struct

Comment: Writing to "/sys/class/gpio/export" causes `export_store()` to be called (it's a "class attribute" handling function registered by `class_register()` during initialization). That calls `gpiod_export()` which calls `device_create_with_groups()` to create the device in the sysfs tree with a set of "device attribute" files specified by `gpio_groups[]`. `dev_attr_value` is defined and initialized by `static DEVICE_ATTR_RW(value);`. `value_store()` is pointed to by `dev_attr_value.store` and is called when the "store" attribute file is written.

Comment: It depends how far behind the scenes you want to go. You can follow the rabbit hole down the call to `device_create_with_groups()` to find out how the sysfs files are created and their file operations set up.

Comment: wow thx! I have zero exp with linux kernel. I found (https://static.lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch14.pdf) because you mentioned class and i get it a little more. I think with more reading i will get it.
You can post as answer if you want.

Any refs to docs/books you used to learn this stuff?

Comment: It's the mysterious appearance of things like the `dev_attr_...` variables that catch people out, since their declarations are hidden by macros. It would probably be less confusing if there were also macros to point to and access these variables.

Comment: There were plans for an LDD 4th edition. You can even see this mythical book as "currently unavailable" on Amazon!